# Matplotlib - How to draw a 3D plane

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to draw a 3D-plane graph using **matplotlib**. I do not understand why I receive an error to indicate `x` and `y` must be the same length.

> In [134]: dat_vis

```
Out[134]: 

   param_C param_gamma  mean_test_score           x  y
4        1       0.001         0.875129           0  1
5        1      0.0001         0.844759           0  0
6       10       0.001         0.903091  0.00900901  1
7       10      0.0001         0.875191  0.00900901  0
8      100       0.001         0.899622   0.0990991  1
9      100      0.0001         0.902420   0.0990991  0
10    1000       0.001         0.909187           1  1
11    1000      0.0001         0.896094           1  0
```

> In [135]: ax.plot_trisurf(dat_vis.x, dat_vis.y, dat_vis.mean_test_score)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-135-1693be3ae757> in <module>()
----> 1 ax.plot_trisurf(dat_vis.x, dat_vis.y, dat_vis.mean_test_score)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py in plot_trisurf(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1976         lightsource = kwargs.pop('lightsource', None)
   1977 
-> 1978         tri, args, kwargs = Triangulation.get_from_args_and_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
   1979         if 'Z' in kwargs:
   1980             z = np.asarray(kwargs.pop('Z'))

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/tri/triangulation.py in get_from_args_and_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
    162             mask = kwargs.pop('mask', None)
    163 
--> 164             triangulation = Triangulation(x, y, triangles, mask)
    165         return triangulation, args, kwargs
    166 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/tri/triangulation.py in __init__(self, x, y, triangles, mask)
     53             # No triangulation specified, so use matplotlib._qhull to obtain
     54             # Delaunay triangulation.
---> 55             self.triangles, self._neighbors = _qhull.delaunay(x, y)
     56             self.is_delaunay = True
     57         else:

ValueError: x and y must be 1D arrays of the same length
```

Comment: **x and y must be a 1D array of the same length** means the condition `x.shape == y.shape` must evaluate to **True**

Comment: In [136]: x.shape == y.shape
Out[136]: True

Comment: Is the shown dataframe `dat_vis` complete or is it larger? Are there any `np.nan` in the dataframe?

Comment: is `dat_vis.x` returning a view on the DataFrame? Maybe you should try `dat_vis["x"].values` which should give you a 1D numpy array?

Comment: ok, i find the problem,the my columns dtype is object. thank you gays help me find this error.

Comment: If you are able to adapt your question to be usable to others you should edit it and answer your own question with your solution.

Comment: ok,thank you, i am trying do it

Comment: Please provide a complete runnable example.

Answer (score 0):

I get the Dataframe object from the sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV(). it return an object dtypes columns, so when i try to use the variance to draw a gragh, it can't be operated well. so if you can't find where the question is ,you should come back and make sure you have a right dtypes.

Comment: This should be a comment. Not an answer

Comment: what should i do? i am new here

Comment: You might want to delete your answer and keep the discussion in the comment section.